# ¿Cómo puedo Generar un encabezado y pie de página con dompdf y laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf

Mi inquietud es referente a que estoy generando pdf con dompdf (barryvdh/laravel-snappy) y laravel y quiero saber como puedo generar un encabezado y pie de página establecido para todas las páginas generadas ya que se pueden generar más de una página. Con una sola no tengo problemas por que las estoy añadiendo con la estructura de header y footer en la vista (pdf/vista.blade.php), pero no se hace que se repita en las demás hojas.

```
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.vista',['entidad'=>$request->dirigidoa,
                      'contacto'=>$request->persona,
                      'ciudad'=>$request->ciudad,
                      'referencia'=>$request->referencias,
                      'nombres'=>$nombres,
                      'descripcion'=>$descripcion,
                      'condicion'=>$condicion,
                      'created_at'=>$datetime]);

    return $pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la imagen ejemplo de lo que tengo al momento sin el error de que se alargue.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si este tipo de preguntas se pueden hacer, cuando comence me hicieron la salvedad, creo que tienes que mostrar el codigo o lo que llevas hecho para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Por favor pega el código  no penas imágenes de código ya que dificultan su legibilidad y que podamos revisarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo haber entendido tu preocupación o necesidad. Si bien te fijas, utilizas el sistema blade de plantillas para las vistas incluido en laravel para funcionar. Por ello, mi recomendación es bien sencilla.

Al igual que tienes un "layout.pdf" o plantilla para todos tus pdf, haz exactamente igual con el header y el footer.

Esto se hace de la siguiente forma.

En el lugar del header y el footer pones:

`@include('partials.pdf.header')`
`@include('partials.pdf.footer')`

Ahora Generas una carpeta llamada "partials" o vistas parciales, que son trocitos de código blade que vas a utilizar de forma dinámica o por otro lado, simplemente para organizar el código.

Dentro de la carpeta `partials`, generas otra para ser organizado, llamada `pdf` (Como he podido ver la estructura de tu proyecto "layout.pdf", supuse que dentro de "plantillas tienes pdf" pues dentro de parciales, otra de pdf. Bueno eso ya como tu te organices.).

Ahora en donde vayas a guardar tus "trozos parciales de header y footer", generas sus plantillas blade. `header.blade.php` y `footer.blade.php`.

Estas dos únicamente van a contener ese trocito que quieres poner en todos tus pdf.

Ahora por último, en tu vista de PDF, si recuerdas, pusimos

`@include('partials.pdf.header')`
`@include('partials.pdf.footer')`

lo que significa que ahí buscará la ruta de tu trocito parcial y la incluirá. Por ello ya puedes podificar el resto del pdf, que siempre esta plantilla ejecutará ese encabezado.

Ahora, si lo que deseas es un encabezado dinámico, puedes también utilizar la lógica de blade para que se ejecuten unas plantillas u otras.

Por ejemplo, 

`@if($headerPdf == 'empresa1')
    @include('partials.pdf.headerEmpresa1')
@else
    @include('partials.pdf.header')
@endif`

Digamos aquí tenemos un header en el "else" que en caso de no encontrar algún caso anterior que coincida, pone un "por defecto llamado header".

Y si la variable que pasaste a la condición if, que vendría del controlador, es positiva, ahí tendrías otro header distinto.

Debo de añadir sobre esta forma, que si tu vista o pdf se ejecuta desde un controlador que no tiene o conoce la variable que has enviado, "$headerPdf", es posible como es lógico que de un error de que no existe la variable.

En mi caso cuando se me da esta situación, lo puedes solucionar con `isset()`

`@if(isset($headerPdf))
   @if($headerPdf == 'empresa1')
       @include('partials.pdf.headerEmpresa1')
   @endif
@else
       @include('partials.pdf.header')
@endif`

Lo que hace es chequear si la variable existe o contiene algo. sino deja pasar

Si bien es cierto que hay mas formas de hacerlo dinámico, como sería enviar directamente las variables desde el controlador y ejecutarlas en el header que tienes ahí en tu imagen, como sería la ruta de la imagen, y de esta forma se mostraría dinámico.

Espero que te ayude. Un saludo =)

PD: Te recomiendo leer la documentación sobre blade, ya que dispone de formas realmente interesantes de manejar tus vistas, agruparlas, organizarlas y ejecutarlas dependiendo de muchos factores, variables o como gustes en realidad. Así pues te paso enlace.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Recuerda valorar de forma positiva si es tu respuesta para ayudar a otros usuarios a encontrarla mas rápido. Saludos